# Open itune link in app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, app-store

My application is in 3 languages, i want to open app store on button click and link is my another application. But when i am sending link to app store , its always opening US market with English description. when i am using browser its going correct. Where i am going wrong.

```
-(IBAction)Button_us_itune:(id)sender{
    NSString *ituneLink =@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/My_application/AppID?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ituneLink]];

}
-(IBAction)Button_fr_itune:(id)sender{
    NSString *ituneLink =@"https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/My_application/AppID?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ituneLink]];
}
-(IBAction)Button_du_itune:(id)sender{
    NSString *ituneLink =@"https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/My_application/AppID?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ituneLink]];
}
```

Comment: It will open app store link of the country which you have set from the settings for itunes account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is might be because you are using/Logged in US store.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's pretty easy. You have two mistakes:

1. You are using country code in the links. i.e. you are mention exactly what store you want to open. This is bad because on some cases the user would open different store than the one you need. If you ask for US and user registered for another one you would lose him.
2. You probably can't tell which store the user is register to. So even if you create the the right link you can never tell which function to call (there is no API to know where the user is registered according to my knowledge - you can just know where he is or his language settings).

So, You could just remove the country code. i.e:

```
NSString *ituneLink =@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/My_application/AppID?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4"
```

But **even then you would probably have problems with the link itself on some cases and in some OS versions**.

**I suggest** you use a simple library called [iLink](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ilink) that would figure out everything (at run time) and create the link you need that would work always. It also have a great feature that would prompt the user for an update if there is one on the store.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving denmark app link. And I think you are logged in with other country.